# Autoload motion-Ui slide at load page with SCSS

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am new to foundation 6 and SCSS. I can make many transitions onclic but i dont know how to active it on load page.

This code are in index.html

```
<div class="testmotion">
<div data-animate="slideInRight" class="slow ease">This is a div.</div>
</div>
```

How i can execute motion-ui-transitions without data-toggler but on body load ?